# Is it possible to include sections of XAML from a separate XAML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, import, include

I have developed a large `WPF` application and would like to extract the different sections of the XAML file into their own XAML files and include them into the main XAML file?

In `PHP` this can be done using `require_once("nameOfFile.php")` and in `Java` it can be done use JSTL's `<c:import>` tag.

**Is it possible to slice up a projects main .XAML file in to several smaller XAML files and include them?**

Comment: For layout sections you can create `UserControl`, or `DataTemplate` and use it as `ContentTemplate` and if it's resources can create `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: Which one is most appropriate if I am binding labels?

Comment: To be honest I would do all of that. Create `UserControl` assuming it works in specific view model `DataContext`, with all bindings, and then create `DataTemplate` that uses your `Usercontrol` as content either with `DataType` for implicit use or `x:Key` for explicit use and put it in some `ResourceDictionary`. It gives you flexibility of using either `UserControl` manually or explicitly using `DataTemplate` or even WPF choosing `DataTemplate` implicitly based on `DataType` and current content

Comment: What do you mean by *main XAML file*? Are you talking about your `App.xaml` file or other resource files? If so, see the [Merged Resource Dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a MVVM compliant project which I worked for a couple of years ago.
I had some XAML "resources" stored in a DB and I needed to retrive them for inserting them in some WPF windows o usercontrols. So I used an attached property.

For simplicity I suppose your resources are in the `App.xaml`, i.e. something like that:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DockPanel x:Key="dockPanel" Margin="2">
            <TextBlock Text="A description..." Margin="0, 0, 2, 0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
            <RichTextBox />
        </DockPanel>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

So you can create an `InsertXamlBehavior` class:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class InsertXamlBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Key", typeof(string), typeof(InsertXamlBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnKeyChanged)));

        public static string GetKey(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(KeyProperty);
        }

        public static void SetKey(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(KeyProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnKeyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            IAddChild addChild = dependencyObject as IAddChild;
            if (addChild != null)
            {
                if (args.NewValue != null)
                {
                    addChild.AddChild(App.Current.FindResource(args.NewValue));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can easly insert the XAML resource in a window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Here an inserted XAML resource..." Margin="2" />
        <Border Margin="2" Padding="4" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" local:InsertXamlBehavior.Key="dockPanel" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Of course you can change the `InsertXamlBehavior` in order to retrieve your XAML from the source your prefer (for example a DB like in my case).